# why Facebook compresses photos uploaded by iPhone 6 plus from my app

Tags: ios, facebook, iphone-6-plus

I'm working on an iOS app which is compatible for iPhone 4,4S,5,5S,6,6 plus, 6S, iPad etc. 
From my app I share the link of the photo on Facebook but unfortunately it appears too blurry only when it is sent via iPhone 6 plus.

[image shared via ios app running on iPhone 6 plus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gxvrk.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Why does Facebook compress images in this way?

Facebook provides image storage free of charge to its users – there is no limit to the number of images you can display on Facebook. But behind the scenes, Facebook has to pay to store the images: costs such as disk drives, bandwidth and data centres must amount to a multi-million dollar bill for them. OK, we can’t feel sorry for them, because they are one of the richest companies on the planet, but even so, it is understandable that they want to reduce their storage and bandwidth outlay.

By compressing images, they reduce their costs. You might upload a 500KB JPG file, but Facebook will compress this down to 100KB or less. This loss of data is responsible for the unwanted artifacts that appear in your image.

More info here..:
http://www.freedigitalphotos.net/blog/tutorials/avoiding-facebook-image-compression/

Comment: I know that Facebook does compress the larger size images. But my question is does it compress depending on the device because I'm experiencing this issue only on iPhone 6 plus.